# KendoUI (js) combobox & binding data from a web-API not working

Tags: javascript, c#, json, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have spent hours trying to figure this out and having no luck!!!

So I have an MVC project that is serving up web API's (Note: Separate project, hosted internally) returning json.

**Sample**:

**URL**: http://api.domain.co.uk/api/locations/sitesdropdown

**Controller**

```
// GET api/Locations/Sitesdropdown
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Sitesdropdowntest()
        {
            var sites = _context.v_dim_HMLocations.Select(l => new
                {
                    SiteName = l.site
                })
                .Distinct();

            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = sites,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
        }
```

**Data returned** UPDATES: 1. Removed synthetic key, 2. Changed method behind returning:

```
{
"ContentEncoding": null,
"ContentType": null,
"Data": [
    {
        "SiteName": "Colworth"
    },
    {
        "SiteName": "Donaldsons"
    },
    {
        "SiteName": "Heathlands"
    },
    {
        "SiteName": "HHP Portugal"
    },
    {
        "SiteName": "Leythorne"
    },
    {
        "SiteName": "Propagation"
    },
    {
        "SiteName": "Sheeplands"
    },
    {
        "SiteName": "Tuesley"
    }
],
"JsonRequestBehavior": 0,
"MaxJsonLength": null,
"RecursionLimit": null
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
    jQuery("#site").kendoComboBox({
        autoBind: true,
        placeholder: "Select Site...",
        dataTextField: "SiteName",
        dataValueField: "SiteName",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://api.domain.co.uk/api/locations/sitesdropdowntest",
                    type: "jsonp"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data"
            },
            serverFiltering: true
        }
    });
```

**Relevant HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="SiteId">Site</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input id="site" />                        
    </div>
</div>
```

The button is rendering perfectly fine as a Kendo UI control - it just doesn't seem to have any data going into it from the dataSource.

[I can see that the combobox is getting the correct data as VS generates one of these little files which has the correct json content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGUnH.png)

I'd really appreciate any help with this!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Returning Entity Framework objects may not be a good option.
You can try using a ModelView to remove "$".

**UPDATE**

See this example: https://github.com/MiguelCosta/kendo-example

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Sitesdropdowntest()
    {
        //var sites = _context.v_dim_HMLocations.Select(l => new
        //{
        //    Id = l.Id,
        //    SiteName = l.site
        //}).ToList();

        // only for test
        var sites = new List<object>
        {
            new { Id = 1, SiteName = "Site1" },
            new { Id = 2, SiteName = "Site2" },
            new { Id = 3, SiteName = "Site3" },
            new { Id = 4, SiteName = "Site4" },
            new { Id = 5, SiteName = "Site5" }
        };

        return Json(sites, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

https://github.com/MiguelCosta/kendo-example/blob/master/Mpc.KendoExample/Mpc.KendoExample/Controllers/LocationsController.cs

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#site").kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField: "SiteName",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/locations/Sitesdropdowntest",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

https://github.com/MiguelCosta/kendo-example/blob/master/Mpc.KendoExample/Mpc.KendoExample/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-2" for="SiteId">Site</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input id="site" />
</div>
```

https://github.com/MiguelCosta/kendo-example/blob/master/Mpc.KendoExample/Mpc.KendoExample/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

**Result:**
[image: Kendo example]

Comment: Hiya, so I have removed the synthetic key - same result. Combobox doesn't appear to be loading any of the data.

Comment: "Combobox doesn't appear to be loading any of the data". This is strange.
Can you show your HTML page?

Comment: Hi Miguel, Thanks for your response - I've added the HTML though it is just an input. Included the controller, updated JS/Returned results. I had a look at the example. The only difference here I can see is that the data source is in the format: callback([ data ]) - do I need my json results to have this Callback wrapper?

Comment: Hi Miguel, I have been able to sort it out. Was nothing to do with the JS or the JSON formatting!! Thanks for your time to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this issue now -

As it turns out it wasn't anything to do with the javascript config or the JSON data formatting.

It was CORS - because my API solution is hosted on a different subdomain it was giving me some errors when trying to make the call.

I have fixed this now by doing the following:

**web.config**

This is what is working now.

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Before I had this line also:

```
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origins" value="*" />
```

Once I removed this I then also added the following to my global.asax

**global.asax***

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Thank you very much for your help - It is greatly appreciated.